# get handlebars path dynamically in stencil theme

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

In my Stencil template I can get an image like this

```
{{cdn 'assets/img/brandcons/ds_4.png'}}
```

but i need to form that path dynamically like this

```
{{#each shop_by_brand}}
    <img src="{{cdn 'assets/img/brandcons/ds_{{id}}.png'}}"> // causes 404
{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each shop_by_brand}}
    <img src="{{cdn 'assets/img/brandcons/ds_'+id+'.png'}}"> // causes 400
{{/each}}
```

That doesnt work for me. How can i do that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper 'concat' as below

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function () {
        var result = "";
        for(var i in arguments) {
            result += (typeof arguments[i] === "string" ? arguments[i] : "") + " ";
        }
        return result;
});
```

and call the helper like,

```
<img src="{{cdn (concat 'assets/img/brandcons/ds_' id '.png') }}">
```

Hope this helps.